# Evolution of sexually concordant genetic variation on the X-chromosome

Tags: evolution, chromosome, sexual-selection

It was [theorised in 1984](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2408385) that sexually antagonistic genetic (SA) variation should more easily evolve on the X-chromosome. This is partly because female beneficial/male deleterious mutations face less powerful selection against them; the X is in females twice as often as in males so mutations will persist up to the point where male cost is <2x the females gain. Furthermore, male beneficial/female deleterious recessive mutations (*p*) will always be expressed in males and, when rare, only very occasionally in females; if the frequency of *p* 0.1 then 1 in 10 males will express that trait and only 1 in 100 of the females.

It is therefore expected that the X-chromosome should become a hotspot for SA variation in comparison to the autosomes. A result would be increased persistence of genetic variation on the X- within sexually antagonistic loci. However, **how would a sexually concordant (male & female beneficial, or male & female deleterious) fare in the X- compared to the autosomes?** Just eyeballing it, it feels like the X- should be better able to select on recessive mutations because they are always expressed in males; removing deleterious and spreading beneficial mutations more rapidly. **Should there then be less genetic variation on the X- than autosomes?**

Comment: I dont really understand what Sexual Antagonism means. However [this](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2014/140821/ncomms5743/full/ncomms5743.html?WT.ec_id=NCOMMS-20140827) article may be relevant to your question. Just happened to see it some days back.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - I briefly touch on sexual antagonism in [my answer to this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/20801/8517). See the last part where I talk about conflict.